# Inkscape: Collapsing everything onto a single layer

Tags: inkscape, layers

Background: I am currently transitioning my workflow from using Illustrator as my primary vector graphics application to using Inkscape. Hence, I have 1000s of images created in Illustrator (and saved as .eps files) that I may want to work with in Inkscape in the future. I also create vector images using PsTricks, and other TeX based packages that I sometimes want to convert and work with in Inkscape.

Situation: Whenever I open one of these .eps files in Inkscape, it comes in with many different layers with random names. (That is, I guess the many folders in the Layers and Objects panel are different layers. When I add a new layer, it appears in a new color, so I am not even sure what these folders are.) These layers, or folders, have nested folders and many objects scattered around in them. In order to edit the objects in image, I need these to all be on one layer. Or at least I want to start out with that, because as it is currently they are completely unorganized and related objects may be on completely different layers, etc.

Question: Is there a way that I can select everything and force it all onto a single layer at once. Currently, I have only been able to select objects in individual folders and move them to the same layer one at a time, or in groups. But since these files are complicated, with many 10s or 100s of objects, this is time consuming.

Comment: It doesn't sound like these are layers. Probably groups and nested groups. Can you show a screen shot of your Layers and Objects panel?  If these are merely nested groups, try Extensions > Arrange > Deep Ungroup.

Comment: If you do in fact have layers left after a deep ungroup, do Edit > Select all in Layers, then Cut, then in the Layers and Objects panel delete all layers except one, then do Edit > Paste > In Place.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer to this question!

Inkscape, collapsing everything onto a single layer from multiple layers can be manual, but here's a step-by-step answer.

**1. Open the Layers panel:**

- Go to `Layer > Layers...` to open the Layers dialog.

**2. Identify Layers:**

- In the Layers dialog, you'll see a list of layers (folders) with objects inside them. These layers might be coming from your imported EPS Files.

**3. Flatten Sublayers:**

- Click on the small triangle icon next to each layer to expand or collapse sublayers. Try to simplify the structure by collapsing unnecessary sublayers.

**4. Select All Objects:**

- Press `Ctrl + A` (Windows/Linux) or `Cmd + A` (Mac) to select all objects in the canvas.

**5. Move to a New Layer:**

- Right-click on any of the selected objects, and choose `Move to Layer > New Layer...`. This will create a new layer with all the selected objects.

**6. Repeat for Other Layers:**

- Repeat steps 2-5 for each layer until all objects are on the new layer.

**7. Remove Empty Layers:**

- After you've moved all objects to the new layer, you can delete the empty layers. `Right-Click` on the empty layer and choose `Delete`.

**8. Organize and Rename:**

- Optionally, you can now organize and rename your layers by right-clicking on them in the layers dialog and choosing `Rename`.

I hope this will work for sure :)